# How is this illegal

Tags: java, arrays

```
a) int i[] = new int[2]{1,2};
b) int[] i = new int[]{1,2,3}{4,5,6};
```

I know we cannot give size of an array at declaration . But in statement(a) we are giving size in initialization . Then how is statement (a) illegal and statement (b) is legal in java

Comment: Check again. You're wrong.

Comment: Both statements are invalid actually.

Comment: Yeah both are invalid. :( Overlooked the size there.

Comment: For primitive type, you don't even need to declare `new int[][]`, just the initializer is sufficient.

Comment: Either `int[] i = new int[]{1, 2, 3};` OR `int[] i = {4, 5, 6};` is valid.

Comment: @shuangwhywhy OR `int i[] = new int[]{1,2,3};` OR `int i[] {4,5,6};` OR `int[] i = new int[3];` OR `int i[] = new int[3];`. I think that covers all the bases excepting multidim arrays.

Comment: Also, the latter two I listed initialize the array full of `0`.

Answer (score 3):

```
int i1[] = new int[]{1,2};
int[][] i2 = new int[][]{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

Comment: There is actually no need for `new` operator at all: `int[] i1 = {1, 2}; int[][] i2 = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };`

Answer (score 3):

```
int i1 [] = new int [2] {1, 2}; // Invalid
int i2 [] = new int [] {1, 2}; // Valid
int [] i3 = new int [][] {1, 2, 3} {4, 5, 6}; // Invalid
int [][] i4 = new int [][] {new int [] {1, 2, 3}, new int [] {4, 5, 6}}; // Valid
```

Comment: Why is 1st statement Invalid.

Comment: @Navi You should either specify array size like `[2]` or array elements like `{1, 2}` but not both.

Answer (score 3):

Why not consult the Java Language Specification?

JLS 15.10 - Array Creation Expressions

```
ArrayCreationExpression:
new PrimitiveType DimExprs Dimsopt
new ClassOrInterfaceType DimExprs Dimsopt
new PrimitiveType Dims ArrayInitializer
new ClassOrInterfaceType Dims ArrayInitializer

DimExprs:
DimExpr
DimExprs DimExpr

DimExpr:
[ Expression ]

Dims:
[ ]
Dims [ ]
```

Notice that this means that array creation expressions with initializers can only have empty brackets.

Array initializers are defined in 10.6

```
ArrayInitializer:
{ VariableInitializersopt ,opt }

VariableInitializers:
VariableInitializer
VariableInitializers , VariableInitializer

The following is repeated from §8.3 to make the presentation here clearer:
VariableInitializer:
Expression
ArrayInitializer
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are illegal!

a) You either specify the size or the content.
Legal would be:

```
int i[] = new int[2];
i[0] = 1;
i[1] = 2;
```

or

```
int i[] = new int[]{1,2};
```

b) 2-dimensional arrays are arrays containing arrays. So, you have to write:

```
int[] i = new int[][]{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
                     ^       ^        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

a) Cannot define dimension expressions when an array initializer is provided
   int i[] = new int[2];
b) Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
   int[] j = new int[]{1,2,3};